# Text search with diacritics in MongoDB not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, character-encoding, case-insensitive

The newer versions of MongoDB support diacritics sensitive search, however I couldn't get them working.

For example if I search `casa` I want it to return documents with `casa` and `casă`.

(I am using mongoose in nodejs)

- Mongo:4,
- mongoose: 5.6.0,

```
this.find(
      { $text: { $search: keyword, $diacriticSensitive: false } },
    )
      .collation({ locale: 'ro', strength: 1 })
```

```
bookSchema.index(
  {
    content: 'text',
    title: 'text',
    code: 'text',
    custom: 'text',
  },
  {
    name: 'SearchIndex',
    weights: { content: 1,   title: 16, code: 2, custom: 8 },
    default_language: 'ro',
    language_override: 'ro',
    collation: { locale: 'ro', strength: 1 }
  }
);
```

Now if I search with diacritics i get only results with diacritics and if I search without, the any documents with diacritics are not found.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? or working example?

Comment: I hope you have seen this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/

Comment: Index type "text" does not support collation. [Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31089)